# Terraform output variables as input

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm new to Terraform and trying to wrap my head around the use of output variables. we are on AKS, and I'm deploying the following resources: resource group, log analytics workspace, Azure Kubernetes.  When Log analytics is deployed, I capture the workspace ID into an output variable. Now, when Terraform deploys Kubernetes, it needs to know the workspace ID, how can I pass the output value to the `addon_profile` (last line in the code below)?

Error:

```
environment = "${log_analytics_workspace_id.value}"

A managed resource "log_analytics_workspace_id" "value" has not been declared in the root module.
```

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "${var.log}"
  location = "${var.location}" 
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "test" {
  name                = "${var.logname}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.loganalytics.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.loganalytics.name}"
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

**output "log_analytics_workspace_id" {
  value = "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.test.workspace_id}"
}** 

....................................................

addon_profile {
      oms_agent {
        enabled                    = true
        **log_analytics_workspace_id = "${log_analytics_workspace_id.value}"**
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Terraform's output values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) are like the "return values" of a module. In order to declare and use the `log_analytics_workspace_id` output value, you would need to put all of the code for the creation of the resource group, log analytics workspace, and Azure Kubernetes infrastructure into a single Terraform module, and then reference the output value from outside of the module:

```
# declare your module here, which contains creation code for all your Azure infrastructure + the output variable
module "azure_analytics" {
  source = "git::ssh://git@github.com..."
}

# now, you can reference the output variable in your addon_profile from outside the module:
addon_profile {
      oms_agent {
        enabled                    = true
        log_analytics_workspace_id = "${module.azure_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id}"
      }
}
```

On the other hand, if you just want to use the `workspace_id` value from your `azurerm_log_analytics_workspace` within the same code, just reference it like `azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.test.workspace_id`.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed. the second option seems easier to implement for now.